# In Sniper Elite V2, how is the kill score calculated?

Tags: sniper-elite-v2

In Sniper Elite V2 for the PC, however available on different platforms. When you kill a target a score is displayed. From what I can gather this score is based upon distance and where the bullet hits. I've looked through the [official forum](http://sniperelitev2.com/Forum/) for some answers on this, however to no avail.

Has anyone worked out or found what the rough formula depends on and how it is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all of the research I have pulled in online, the only thing that I could find was this:

- There is a bonus score multiplier of 8% for each successive kill you make. This is reset if you miss but not after an amount of time has elapsed. It also doesn't matter if its a headshot, just so long as you kill them in one shot.
- Performing a 2 for 1 bullet kill only adds 8% despite you killing two people in quick succession, not 16%.
- A land-mine kill will score higher than a trip wire kill.

Also read somewhere that `score depends on how many vital organs you hit with a single shot`, but I couldn't find any evidence to support this.

The main three factors seem to be `Range`, `Hit Location` and 'Number of Kills in One Shot`. Other than that, there doesn't seem to be an exact formula (even rough)

Comment: Oh, never even thought about the multiplier. Thanks